# Python taking too long to read and write large files into text file

Tags: python, python-3.6, wireshark, pcap

I a beginner in python and am having trouble trying to store an output of a PCAP file from wireshark into a text file. The code works, but it takes way too long to read the PCAP file as it is 300+ MB in size with 157167 lines of text.

Is there a way I can make it run faster? Here is the source code:

```py
import pyshark
from datetime import datetime

def network_conversation(packet):
  try:
    protocol = packet.transport_layer
    source_address = packet.ip.src
    source_port = packet[packet.transport_layer].srcport
    destination_address = packet.ip.dst
    destination_port = packet[packet.transport_layer].dstport
    packet_time = packet.sniff_time
    packet_length = []
    packet_length = int(packet.length)
    return (f'{packet_time} {protocol} {source_address}:{source_port} --> {destination_address}:{destination_port} {packet_length}')
  except AttributeError as e:
    pass

capture = pyshark.FileCapture('YouTube.pcap')
date=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')
conversations = []
for packet in capture:
  results = network_conversation(packet)
  if results != None:
    conversations.append(results)

# this sorts the conversations by protocol 
# TCP and UDP
for item in sorted(conversations):
  with open(f"capture{date}.txt", "a+") as f:
    print(item, file=f)
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to open the file before the for-loop at the end of your script. The way its currently written, your script will try to open the same file, and set its cursor to the end at the start of every iteration, which can slow down your application.

Comment: @CarlHR 
pcap = open(f"capture{date}.txt", "a+")
for item in sorted(conversations):
    print(item, file=pcap)

I wrote this and it still runs with the same problem :(

Comment: Where does it take too long to execute? Inside `network_conversation(packet)`? Or is it when you call `pyshark.FileCapture('YouTube.pcap')`?

Comment: @CarlHR The YouTube.pcap file is an already existing file that I have exported from wireshark. I just started a capture sniffed some packets from youtube and exported it as a pcap file. I have no idea if that has to do with anything regarding internet speed, I am just loading the file I exported, going through it line by line, and then printing the results onto a text file. Sorry for the long reply, I hope you understand what I meant by that.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm not familiar with the wireshark api. I though that you were donwloading the file every time the script executed. My bad.

Comment: That's okay haha, I am just trying to find a way to just store this result in a quicker way. Because I have seen this done in many big projects/applications. Since I am a beginner in python, I don't have the necessary skills yet to make my programs run faster. Hoping someone will come in handy and help me out with this one :)

Comment: I don't see anything in your problem statement that would support the conclusion that writing the result is the bottleneck. It's possible that writing the data is the bottleneck but it seems to me you've jumped to a hasty conclusion without data supporting that conclusion. Add some print statements that output the time delta for each major op in the code. And, please, fix your example so you open the file and do the `for item...print` inside. The way you're doing it is going to eliminate any buffering of the output; not to mention the cost of opening and closing the file for every item output.

Comment: Obviously, in addition to updating your question to show that you only open the output file once you should also test that variant. I expect that change will have a big impact on the run time. It may still be the case that writing the results is the bottleneck but it should be significantly more efficient.